# Channels, Bootstrap Carousel and ExpressionEngine driving me insane

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, expressionengine, carousel, channel

I know somebody already had their problem fixed on here regarding channels and expressionengine, but nothing worked for me! Still really struggling. I can get only one post to show in the carousel, the buttons do not show any other slide and it is driving me **mad**!!

If anyone can help, I really would appreciate it. The code I have so far is:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  {exp:channel:entries channel="front_page" limit="1" dynamic="off"}
  <div class="{if count==1}active {/if}item">
    {body}
  </div>
  {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a> 
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
```

I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the limit="1" parameter would be my first suggestion.